# make number on a specific pattern

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop

I want a code that makes a number on a specific pattern. For example:

- If the number is in range 0-39 then it makes 0.
- If the number is in range 40-79 it makes it 40.
- If the number is in range 80-119 it makes it 80 and so on...

Here is the code that I was trying:

```
for(int t=1 ; t<300 ; t=t*10){
    if(t+40 > somenumber && t-40 < sumnumber){
        System.out.println("match  "+t);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i = i - (i % 40)

Comment: You have a vague requirement and it seems a homework question. One of the goals of a homework is that the person needs to do it himself so that he would comprehend the scope of the assigned task.

Comment: `somenumber / 40 * 40`

Comment: for(int t=1 ; t<300 ; t=t*10){
    final double match = Math.floor(t / 40) * 40;
    System.out.println("match  "+ match);
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `int division` : `86/40 = 2` because it keeps only the `int part` (`86/40.0 would give 2.15`

*If `step` was a `double`, you would need `res = step * Math.floor(t / step)`*

```
int step = 40;
for (int t = 1; t < 300; t += 10) {
   int res = step * (t / step);
   System.out.printf("%3d => %3d%n", t, res);
}
/*
  1 =>   0
 11 =>   0
 21 =>   0
 31 =>   0
 41 =>  40
 51 =>  40
 61 =>  40
 71 =>  40
 81 =>  80
 91 =>  80
101 =>  80
111 =>  80
121 => 120
131 => 120
141 => 120
151 => 120
161 => 160
171 => 160
181 => 160
191 => 160
201 => 200
211 => 200
221 => 200
231 => 200
241 => 240
251 => 240
261 => 240
271 => 240
281 => 280
291 => 280
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you want is to know how many int times 40 is in your number: for 39 it's 0, for 40...79 it's 1 and so on? that's just:

`System.out.println(40*(somenumber/40));`

Since
`(somenumber/40)` is an int division it will give you the number of times and since you want the lower bound just multiply it again by `40`.